# JPA Map mapping to join table with 3 columns

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I have list that is mapped by a join table. What I need to do is make the combinations of "layouts" and 'views' not unique and also each with an index. What I thought of trying to do is making a `Map<Integer, View>` and somehow make the join table have a third column 'id'. What would happen is get the views of that layout and populate them with the id from the join table as a key in the map.

Any idea how to do that, or maybe a better idea for what I need?

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
    name = "layout_view",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "layout_id", nullable = false)},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "view_id", nullable = false)}
)
private List<View> views;
```

What I imagine:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
    name = "layout_view",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "layout_id", nullable = false)},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "view_id", nullable = false)}
    //some code for third column and populating it as keys
)
private Map<Integer, View> views;
```

Comment: What is this Integer for? Is it just to preserve the order of the views? If not, what is it for? Also, int is a primitive type. You can't use it as a generic type.

Comment: Yes, sorry about the int in the Map. I would use Integer ofcourse.
As what is it for - I need to be able to change the order and also to have it as unique key so I can have multiple same views for a layout.

Comment: You can already have multiple same views for a layout by using a List, as you're doing. To preserve (and be able to change) the order, see https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html and https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-list. The same documentation also describes how to implement your original idea with a map, if you really want that.

Comment: Yes that works perfectly! Thank you. Post it as an answer If you want me to choose it for best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can already have multiple same views for a layout by using a List, as you're doing.

To preserve (and be able to change) the order, see [OrderColumn](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html) and the [Hibernate documentation about ordered lists](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-list)​.

The same documentation also describes how to implement your original idea with a map, if you really want that.